# How to Interpolate a Partial Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, interpolation

I have a dataframe, which I would like to partially interpolate.  Here is the data:

```
Date    Loc Value
1/1/2018    a   1
2/1/2018    a   2
3/1/2018    a   nan
1/1/2018    b   1
2/1/2018    b   nan
3/1/2018    b   3
```

And the pivot table with the data:

```
           a    b
1/1/2018    1   1
2/1/2018    2   nan
3/1/2018    nan 3
```

I would like to interpolate (bring most recent value forward) only column/location B.  Leave column A as is.  The end result would be a pivot table.

```
df.interpolate(method='values')
```

Will complete the operation on all of the data, but I can't see a way to alter only a sub set of the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the data with Loc == b and interpolate the values, then pivot

```
df.loc[df['Loc'] == 'b', 'Value']= df.loc[df['Loc'] == 'b', 'Value'].interpolate()
df.pivot(index = 'Date', columns = 'Loc', values = 'Value')

Loc         a       b
Date        
1/1/2018    1.000   1.000
2/1/2018    2.000   2.000
3/1/2018    nan     3.000
```

OR, interpolate the required column on your pivoted data

```
df['b'] = df['b'].interpolate()
```